# How to change category and year archive permalinks/rewrite rules?

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, archives

first of ll I'd like to find a way to substitute 'category' with 'events' in permalinks.

Currently I've got this:

http://example.com/category/post-name/

And I would like it to be:

http://example.com/events/post-name/

Secondly, I'd like year archives like this:

http://example.com/events/2021/

And last, I'd like single posts like this:

http://example.com/events/2021/post-name/

---

Now, I can do this with custom post types and taxonomies. But this time I'd like to use regular post/categories, and can't find a good way. Is there a way?